# Not able to push $log data to txt file

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I have a local amp setup where I am trying to push angular $log messages to a txt file. But I keep getting a javaScript error. Here is the error

```
angular.js:9101 TypeError: $scope.todos.push is not a function
```

Here is my code:

```js
angular.module('Todo', []).factory('myhttpserv', function($http) {
  return $http.get('storage.txt').error(function(status) {
    console.log(status)
  });
}).controller('TodoController', function($scope, myhttpserv, $http) {
  $scope.appTitle = "MyTodoList",
    myhttpserv.then(function(response) {
      $scope.todos = (response.data !== null) ? response.data : [];
      var httpPost = function() {
        $http.post('save.php', JSON.stringify($scope.todos)).error(function(status) {
          console.log(status)
        });
      };

      $scope.addTodo = function() {
        $scope.todos.push({
          text: $scope.todoText,
          doneProd: false,
          doneDev: false
        });
        $scope.todoText = ''; //clear the input after adding
        httpPost();
      };

      $scope.remaining = function() {
        var count = 0;
        angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo) {
          count += todo.doneProd && todo.doneDev ? 0 : 1;
        });
        return count;
      };

      $scope.archive = function() {
        var rusure = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove the completed tasks from the list?");
        if (rusure) {
          var oldTodos = $scope.todos;
          $scope.todos = [];

          angular.forEach(oldTodos, function(todo) {
            if (!todo.doneProd || !todo.doneDev)
              $scope.todos.push(todo);
          });
          httpPost();
        }
      };

      $scope.delete = function(idx) {
        var rusure = confirm("Are you sure you want to remove the task from the list?");
        if (rusure) {
          $scope.todos.splice(idx, 1);
          httpPost();
        }
      };

      $scope.edit = function(idx) {
        var changes = prompt("Please make the changes below", $scope.todos[idx].text);
        if (changes != null) {
          $scope.todos[idx].text = changes;
          httpPost();
        }
      };

      $scope.checkboxClick = function() {
        httpPost();
      };

      $('.splash, .container').fadeToggle();
    });
});
```

```html
<div class="splash">
    <h2>Loading</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <header class="app-header">
      <h1 class="app-title" data-ng-bind="appTitle"></h1>
    </header>
    <section class="app-body">

      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>
              TITLE
            </th>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            <th class="chk">
              PROD
            </th>
            <th class="chk">
              DEV
            </th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr data-ng-repeat="todo in todos track by $index">
            <td>
              <span class="done-{{ todo.doneProd && todo.doneDev }}" data-ng-bind="todo.text"></span>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a data-ng-click="delete($index)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td>
              <a data-ng-click="edit($index)"><i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o"></i></a>
            </td>
            <td class="chk">
              <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="todo.doneProd" data-ng-change="checkboxClick()">
            </td>
            <td class="chk">
              <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="todo.doneDev" data-ng-change="checkboxClick()">
            </td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>

      <section class="archive-control">
        <span>{{ remaining() }} of {{ todos.length }} remaining</span>
        <a class="fr" href="" data-ng-click="archive()" data-ng-show="remaining() < todos.length">Remove Completed Items</a>
      </section>

      <form data-ng-submit="addTodo()" class="todo-form">
        <input type="text" data-ng-model="todoText" placeholder="Enter new task item" />
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Add Task" />
      </form>
    </section>
  </div>
```

here is my php file and I do have my storage.txt in the folder also:

```
<?php
   $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
   $myfile = fopen("log.txt", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
   fwrite($myfile, $data);
   fclose($myfile);
?>
```

Comment: Provide an MVCE of the issue. CSS seems irrelevant. Also JS error would be useful.

Comment: My fault the js error is : angular.js:9101 TypeError: $scope.todos.push is not a function

Comment: is $scope.todos an array when push() is called?

Comment: This is what is called before $scope.todos = (response.data !== null) ? response.data : [];
            var httpPost = function () {
                $http.post('save.php', JSON.stringify($scope.todos)).error(function (status) { console.log(status) });
            };

Comment: instead of using "push" is it possible for you to implement a function that "push" the element into the array? I'm not in angular, but the feeling is something wrong about the array, maybe an handmade function that works on the array could lead you on some more information about the error.